# How to access camera in Mac OS Mojave Swift playground

Tags: swift, avfoundation, swift-playground

How to access the camera in Swift playgrounds on Mac OS Mojave?
This used to work with no problem on High Sierra however the code does not seem to execute correctly any more as the playgrounds running symbol is spinning continuously as well as the camera lights staying off.

I got an example of the code which used to work fine last year but not any more today  does anyone know what's wrong and how to fix it?

```
import Cocoa
import AVFoundation
import AVKit
import QuartzCore
import PlaygroundSupport

let view = NSView(frame: NSRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 640.0, height: 480.0))

let session = AVCaptureSession()

session.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSession.Preset.vga640x480
session.beginConfiguration()
session.commitConfiguration()


var input : AVCaptureDeviceInput
if let devices : [AVCaptureDevice] = AVCaptureDevice.devices() as? [AVCaptureDevice] {
for device in devices {
    if device.hasMediaType(AVMediaType.video) && device.supportsSessionPreset(AVCaptureSession.Preset.vga640x480) {
        do {
            input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: device as AVCaptureDevice) as AVCaptureDeviceInput

            if session.canAddInput(input) {
                session.addInput(input)
                break
            }
        }
        catch {
            error
        }
    }
}

let output = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()
output.videoSettings = [kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as AnyHashable as! String: Int(kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA)]
output.alwaysDiscardsLateVideoFrames = true

if session.canAddOutput(output) {
    session.addOutput(output)
}

let captureLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: session)
view.wantsLayer = true
view.layer = captureLayer

session.startRunning()

//View -> Assistant Editor -> Show Assistant Editor
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = view

}
```

Looked at apples documentation on how to request access to the camera I tried it however it does not seem to work in playgrounds as I'm still having the same issue when this is implemented.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/cameras_and_media_capture/requesting_authorization_for_media_capture_on_macos

```
switch AVCaptureDevice.authorizationStatus(for: .video) {
case .authorized: // The user has previously granted access to the camera.
    self.setupCaptureSession()

case .notDetermined: // The user has not yet been asked for camera access.
    AVCaptureDevice.requestAccess(for: .video) { granted in
        if granted {
            self.setupCaptureSession()
        }
    }

case .denied: // The user has previously denied access.
    return
case .restricted: // The user can't grant access due to restrictions.
    return
}
```